# How can i update a directive $scope from other directive contoller in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a diretive with a list of events loading from my service service:

```
.directive('appointments', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'CE',
            scope: {
                ngTemplate: '=',
            },
            controller: ['$scope','calendarService', function ($scope, calendarService) {
               var vm = this;
               vm.events = calendarService.getEvents();
            }],
            controllerAS:'vm',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                    if (angular.isDefined(scope.ngTemplate))
                        return scope.ngTemplate;
                    else
                    return "/list.directive.html";
                }
            },
            template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
        }
    }])
```

Now in another directive i am updating this list, how can i update the list in the first controller?

```
    .directive('appointmentsUpdate', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'CE',
                scope: {
                    ngEventId: '=',
                },
                controller: ['$scope','calendarService', function ($scope, calendarService) {
                   var vm = this;
                   vm.update = calendarService.updateEvent(scope.ngEventId).then(function(res){


   // Here is where the newly created item, should be added to the List (vm.events) from first directive

)
});
                }],
                controllerAS:'vm',
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                        if (angular.isDefined(scope.ngTemplate))
                            return scope.ngTemplate;
                        else
                        return "/list.directive.html";
                    }
                },
                template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
            }
        }])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **angular broadcast service** for this:

in first directive use this:

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast('greeting', data_needs_to_be_send);
```

in other directive listen the event to update its scope:

```
$scope.$on('greeting', listenGreeting)

  function listenGreeting($event, message){
    alert(['Message received',message].join(' : '));
  }
```

Comment: is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: yeah you can do this and will always work, because its an angular  feature. but it's not only way you can also use service.but its super easy to implement.

Comment: I think this is the proper way to communication between two directives. Using $broadcast and $emit will create loosely coupled directives. My recommendation is to use $scope.$broadcast if your 'appointmentsUpdate' directive is a child element of 'appointments' directive. $rootScope will broadcast the event to all children scopes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

We use `require` property to make communication between directives.

Something like this

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: '^ParentDirective or ^SameLevelDirective'
}
```

Here is the clear explanation of [Driectives That Communicate by ToddMotto](https://toddmotto.com/directive-to-directive-communication-with-require/)

Comment: can you please provide an example of this based on the code above? I read through the article and tried, but its not working?!

Answer (score 0):

Services are singletons, so if you update the list from one place (with your `calendarService.updateEvent()`), then if you retrieve the data from the service in the other directive, it should be the updated list.
You could use a watch to check when the list is updated:

```
$scope.$watch(() => calendarService.getEvents(), (newValue, oldValue) => {
    // update your scope with the new list
}, true);
```